# remove the first and last character in an xml file = Need to remove the quote

Tags: xml, oracle, oracle10g

I have a xml like below as a CLOB in an oracle column
How can i get rid of the first and last quotes.
Thanks in Advance

```
"<?xml version = '1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<b></>"
```

Comment: How do you get rid of them in code? If so, which language? Or do you mean in SQL? Or do you mean when reading from the database? I can't think of how to answer without more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear what you are asking, what you are trying to accomplish, or whether your data example is realistic or not, but here is an untested guess at what might help you:

```
UPDATE your_table
   SET your_clob_column = TRIM(BOTH '"' FROM your_clob_column)
 WHERE your_primary_key = 1;
```

Or maybe it's an XMLType with CLOB storage?

```
DECLARE
    v_str   VARCHAR2(1000);
BEGIN
    SELECT your_xmltype_column.getStringVal()
      INTO v_str
      FROM your_table
     WHERE your_primary_key = 1;

    v_str := TRIM(BOTH '"' FROM v_str);

    UPDATE your_table
       SET your_xmltype_column = XMLType(v_str)
     WHERE your_primary_key = 1;

END;
```

Comment: Thanks.All i wanted is to get rid of the quotes before the < and the last one after the > so that i can select data from the XML data.
Will give it a try.
Cheers

Comment: @naijacoder would you consider marking this as an accepted answer if it solved your problem?